# C# MVC controller called twice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am making a C# Razor MVC web app that is geared for Ipad. I am using JQuery mobile and Kendo UI. I have 2 input forms that use the Kendo grid that sit in a JQuery popup window.

My problem is that the Waste_Read controller is double firing and makes 2 kendo grids. This is unnoticeable in desktop apps but on the ipad 2 grids are visible.

Below is my _Layout.cshtml and Ham.cshtml (which is my view) code.

Thanks!

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
@{

if (Session["currentDate"] == null)
{
HttpContext.Current.Session["currentDate"] = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}

if (Session["currentShift"] == null)
{
HttpContext.Current.Session["currentShift"] = 1;
}

if (Session["ReportType"] == null)
{
HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportType"] = "Daily";
}

}

<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width=device-width" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<link href="~/Resources/Triangle.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

@Styles.Render("~/Content/mobileCss", "~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.silver.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.dataviz.silver.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/jquery.min.js")"></script>*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2013.1.319/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
@*<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


//prevents ipad vertical bounce scrolling
document.ontouchmove = function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
}

function UpdateDate() {
UpdateSessionDate();
UpdateSessionShift();
UpdateSessionReportType();

//$('#datepick').val('AT(Session["currentDate"])');

var DatePageType = '@(ViewBag.DatePageType)';

if (DatePageType == "Reporting") {

UpdateCharts();
}
if (DatePageType == "LiveView") {
UpdateViews($('#hoursaver').val());
UpdateLineViews($('#hoursaver').val());
UpdateOverallInfoBox($('#linesaver').val());
UpdateOverviewOfLabourChart()
}
if (DatePageType == "LabourEntry") {
// UpdateViews($('#hoursaver').val());
refreshLabourEntry();
}

}

function UpdateShift() {
UpdateSessionDate();
UpdateSessionShift();

//$('#datepick').val('AT(Session["currentDate"])');

var DatePageType = '@(ViewBag.DatePageType)';

if (DatePageType == "Reporting") {
UpdateCharts();
}
if (DatePageType == "LiveView") {
UpdateViews($('#hoursaver').val());
UpdateLineViews($('#hoursaver').val());
UpdateOverallInfoBox($('#linesaver').val());
}
if (DatePageType == "LabourEntry") {
refreshLabourEntry();

}
}

function pullfrompeviousLoad(objThis) {
var url = $(objThis).data('url') + '?hour=' + $(objThis).data('hour') + '&Shift=' + $(objThis).data('shift') + '&LineName=' + $(objThis).data('line');
window.location.href = url;
}

function menuLoad(objThis) {
var url = $(objThis).data('url');
window.location.href = url;
}

function buttonLoad(objThis) {
var url = $(objThis).data('url') + '?hour=' + $(objThis).data('time');
window.location.href = url;
}

function saveLoad(objThis) {

$('#labourform').submit();
var url = $(objThis).data('url') + '?hour=' + $(objThis).data('time');
window.location.href = url;
return false;
}

// update date session data
function UpdateSessionDate() {

$.post('/SetSession/SetVariable',
{
key: "currentDate",
value: kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
});

};

// update shift session data
function UpdateSessionShift() {

$.post('/SetSession/SetVariable',
{
key: "currentShift",
value: $('#shift').val()
});

};


// update report type session data
function UpdateSessionReportType() {

$.post('/SetSession/SetVariable',
{
key: "ReportType",
value: $('#ReportType').val()
});

};

function UpdateButtons(h) {
var arrayToModify = [];
var i = 0, j, k, buttonsToCreate, buttonContainer, newButton;
var buttonsToCreate = [];
var now = parseInt(h);

for (var j = (now - 7) ; j <= (now + 7) ; j++) {

if (j >= 0 && j <= 23) {
buttonsToCreate[i] = j;
i++;
}
}

buttonContainer = document.getElementById('ddShift');

for (k = 0; k < buttonsToCreate.length; k++) {

if (buttonsToCreate[k] == parseInt(h) + 1) {
newButton.style.cssText = 'background-color: red;';
}

newButton = document.createElement('input');
newButton.type = 'button';
newButton.value = buttonsToCreate[k];
newButton.id = buttonsToCreate[k];
newButton.onclick = function () {
arrayToModify[arrayToModify.length] = this.id;
$('#hoursaver').val(this.id);
UpdateViews(this.id);
UpdateLineViews(this.id);
};

buttonContainer.appendChild(newButton);
}
};

kendo.culture("en-US");

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="index">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
<a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Menu</a>

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
@Html.ActionLink("My Account", "Index", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "gear" })
}
else
{
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { data_icon = "gear" })
}


<div class="datepickerbtn" style="width: 212.5px;">

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
.Name("datepicker")
.Events(e =>
{
e.Change("UpdateDate");
})
.Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
.Value((String)Session["currentDate"])
)
</div>

<div class="shiftpickerbtn" id="btnshift">
<select id="shift" name="shift" onchange="UpdateShift()">
<option value="1">Shift 1</option>
<option value="2">Shift 2</option>
</select>
</div>


</div>
<div data-role="content">

@RenderBody()
</div>
<div data-role="footer" style="text-align: center" data-position="fixed">
@RenderSection("footer", false)
</div>
<div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" id="nav-panel">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
<li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Home</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "LabourEntry")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Labour Entry</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "LiveView")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Live View</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Report")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Reporting</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Loin", "ScheduleBuilder")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Schedule Builder</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("About", "Home")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">About</a></li>
<li><a data-url="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")" onclick="menuLoad(this)">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>

</div>

@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**Ham.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<OPS.Models.LabourSchedule>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Ham";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.DatePageType = "LabourEntry";
}

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

//set the value of the datepicker and Shift via session variables
$('#datepicker').val('@(Session["currentDate"])');
$('#shift').val('@(Session["currentShift"])');
$('#shift').selectmenu('refresh');

$('#lblWasteFormDate').html('@(Session["currentDate"])');

});

function Update_Data() {
return {
CurDate: kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
};
}

function Read_Data() {
return {
LineName: "Ham",
CurDate: kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
ShiftName: @(Session["currentShift"]) + ""
};
}

function Read_DT_Data() {
return {
LineName: "Ham",
CurDate: kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), "yyyy-MM-dd"),
ShiftName: $("#shift").val() + ""
};
}

</script>


@section footer
{
<div data-inline="true">

<div data-inline="true">
@if (ViewBag.curHour > 0)
{                                    
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Ham", "LabourEntry")" onclick="buttonLoad(this)"  data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-time="@ViewBag.prevHour"></a>                  
}
@for (var i = ViewBag.curHour - 7; i <= ViewBag.curHour + 7; i++)
{

if (ViewBag.curHour == i)
{                            
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="b" data-inline="true">@i</a>                                
}
else if (@i >= 0 && @i <= 23)
{                             
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Ham", "LabourEntry")" onclick="buttonLoad(this)" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-time="@i">@i</a>                                          

}

}
@if (ViewBag.curHour < 23)
{                                                          
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-url="@Url.Action("Ham", "LabourEntry")" onclick="buttonLoad(this)"  data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" data-time="@ViewBag.nextHour">Arrow right</a>                    
}
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b">Options</a>
</div>

</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDownTime" class="ui-content" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="width: 80%; position: relative; margin: 20px auto;">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>

<div id="update-message"></div>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "DTForm" }))
{

<input type="hidden" name="LineName" value="Ham" />
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<label for="categories">Downtime Reason:</label>
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("DTCatId")
.OptionLabel("Select downtime...")
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90%;" })
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("ID")
.DataSource(source =>
{
source.Read(read =>
{
read.Action("GetDowntimeCategories", "LabourEntry");
});
})
)
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="txt_DT_Duration">Duration (minutes):</label>
<input type="number" name="DT_Duration" pattern="[0-9]*" id="txt_DT_Duration" value="" />
</td>
<td>
<label for="txt_DT_People"># of People:</label>
<input type="number" name="DT_People" pattern="[0-9]*" id="txt_DT_People" value="" />
</td>
<td>
<label for="sl_Hrs_Type">Hours Type:</label>
<select name="Hrs_Type" id="sl_Hrs_Type" data-role="slider">
<option value="OT">OT</option>
<option value="REG" selected="selected">Reg</option>
</select>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<label for="txt_DT_Desc">Description Detail:</label>
<textarea rows="12" name="DT_Desc" id="txt_DT_Desc"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Downtime" />
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OPS.Models.DownTime>()
.Name("DTGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.DT_ID).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.HR_TYPE).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.LINE_ID).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.SHIFT).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.USER_ID).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.DT_REASON).Title("Reason");
columns.Bound(p => p.DT_DETAIL).Title("Details");
columns.Bound(p => p.DURATION).Title("Duration (mins)");
columns.Bound(p => p.NUM_EFFECTED).Title("# of People");
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
toolbar.Save();
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model =>
{
model.Id(p => p.ID);
})
.Batch(true)
.ServerOperation(false)
.Events(events => events.Error("error"))              
.Read(read => read.Action("DT_Read", "LabourEntry")
.Data("Read_DT_Data"))
.Update(update => update.Action("DT_Update", "LabourEntry"))
)
)
</td>
</tr>
</table>

}
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupWaste" class="ui-content" data-theme="d" data-overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="width: 90%; position: relative; margin: 20px auto;">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>

<div style="width: 100%;">

<h3>Date: <label id="lblWasteFormDate"></label>
</h3>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OPS.Models.LineProductWasteEntry>()
.Name("WasteGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{

columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.BucketWeight).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.LineCategoryId).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.LineCategoryProduct).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.LineProductId).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.ShiftId).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.SourceId).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.UserId).Hidden(true);
columns.Bound(p => p.CategoryName);
columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
columns.Bound(p => p.Value);
columns.Bound(p => p.SourceName);
columns.Bound(p => p.Source);
columns.Bound(p => p.Weight);
columns.Bound(p => p.Weight2);
columns.Bound(p => p.Weight3);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
toolbar.Save();
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Model(model =>
{
model.Id(p => p.Id);
model.Field(p => p.SourceName).Editable(false);
model.Field(p => p.CategoryName).Editable(false);
model.Field(p => p.ProductName).Editable(false);
model.Field(p => p.Value).Editable(false);
})
.Batch(true)
.ServerOperation(false)
.Events(events => events.Error("error"))        
.Read(read => read.Action("Waste_Read", "LabourEntry")
.Data("Read_Data"))
.Update(update => update.Action("Waste_Update", "LabourEntry")
.Data("Update_Data"))

)

)

</div>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="a">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width: 270px;" data-theme="a" class="nav-search">
<li><a href="#popupWaste" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add Waste</a></li>
<li><a href="#popupDownTime" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Add Downtime</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's highly doubtful we will be able to help as you've just given us a big dump of markup to look at. If you could format it nicely and condense it into a smaller block with relevant Kendo information someone should be able to help.

Comment: Are you loading your "Ham.cshtml" as a prtial view?

if it is the case then may be the java script libraries called twice and causes twice calling submitting. I have experienced it already, but not sure if this is your case.

Comment: OMG! What happened to all your indentation?

Answer (score 3):

Only situation where I can think of a form posting twice is when you have a javascript function binded to the click of your submit button which then calls form.submit()

If that is anything like what you are currently doing then try doing e.preventDefault before calling the form.submit()

```
$('#mySubmitButton').click(function(e) {

         e.preventDefault(); //This prevent the submit button onclick from submitting by itself
         $('#myForm').submit(); //Manually call the form submit
});

$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default here as well - this will allow you to do 
                          //your own posts without the defaults running (good for when you want to use ajax)
     // Simple ajax post using whatever action you put in your form 
     if ($(this).valid()) {
           $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                })
           });
     }
});
```

This will ensure that your form will execute only once

Answer (score 0):

In a much more complex setting I noticed my controller got hit more than once. When I remedied the following two things it no longer got a double hit:

- IMG tags with `src="#"`  (placeholders for lazy loading images from
  javascript) remove the hashtag  ==> `src=""`
- `@Url.Content("~/some/static/path/some.css")` remove the call to
  Url.Content ==> `"/some/static/path/some.css"`  (of course that path
  needs to exist)

It is actually not very clear why `@Url.Content()` is hitting the controller again but thorough testing proved it.